# Views getting flagged inside CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

Everything with my android studio was working fine until I came across this weird thing that when I add `Views` inside a `CardView`the IDE is warning me telling that for example "TextView is not allowed here". I have done this a thousand times before and It was absolutely fine.

Here is a List of the things I have tried
1. Restarted the IDE.
2. Restarted the entire system.
3. Tried the Invalidate Caches/Restart thing.
4. Cleaned the peoject.
5. Verified the support library version and files
6. Banged my head against the wall.

Nothing worked, here are some additional details

IDE version 1.3.1, SDK tools is using API 22 fully updated

And one more thing is suggestions are not shown under the CardView in XML, i guess both these problems are related.

I have seen a similar question [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwigzLPeiLDHAhXRH44KHXGTANE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27440887%2Flinearlayout-flagged-if-used-in-cardview&ei=1szRVaCJAtG_uATxpoKIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEgPmF6Q9dvK_Woo9oL2BkUTFEjzg&sig2=XZg2fJV7E0YWYJpu_D0GXA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E), but unfortunately it didn't help me.... Please someone find a fix for this problem...

Comment: i don't believe this would be stopping you from building and running your app

Comment: yes it won't, but its extremely frustrating when you don't get suggestions and other functionalities an IDE is supposed to give...

Comment: i could only recommend to probably update your android studio if it has not been upgraded as it is mentioned in the similar question that people have reported it as a genuine bug though they say that restarting has solved it for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after spending a day searching around in the Intelli J IDEA docs, I was able to find a solution for this problem. It has to do with the corrupted project metadata and other project related data that is common across projects loaded into Android Studio, so naturally I just opened a backup of my project that I had backed up when the problem did not exist. And I solved it....

Hope this'll help you...